# Please help shed light on this theorem (code extensions?)

Tags: coding-theory

The following is a lecture slide. A couple of questions:

1) Is "code extension" being used correctly here? From my googling, what is described doesn't seem to be a code extension.

2) Does $C$ really have length $2n$? For each word $\vec a$, surely there are more than two $\vec a + \vec b$ that can be appended?

3) Is there an alternate statement of this theorem anywhere on the internet? I don't think I have properly understood the construction of $C$.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In the coding theory class I took, I was told that an extended code is one where the dimension stays the same but the length increases. So, in that sense, $C$ is neither an extension of $A$ nor $B$. However, I don't have any references on that, other than my personal class notes.
2. Yes, $C$ has length $2n$. I think you might be misunderstanding the notion of the 'length' of a block code. The 'length' is the number of symbols in each codeword. For example, $0000$ has length 4 and $AB6D29$ has length 6. For a block code, each codeword has the same length, so the length of the code is well-defined.

As for (3), I'm not sure where to find an alternate statement. The construction of that code seems pretty specific, so perhaps your lecturer/professor came up with it as an example.

Comment: Thanks Snowball. (1) is what I understand from my research too.  (2) Oh yes, thanks! I had overcomplicated things and was confusing myself, hehe.

Comment: +1 I agree that it is non-standard to call this an extended code. I might call it "Extension of A by B" or something like that, by usually extending a code simply means adding an overall parity bit.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks for your input!

Comment: @Snowball It is not a specific construction that Ryan's instructor came up with; it is about 50 years old.  See my answer for some details

Comment: @DilipSarwate: Thanks! It's nice to see how that theorem is applied.

Answer (score 4):

The construction in question is sometimes called the *Plotkin* construction. It is described in Chapter 2, Section 9, of MacWilliams and Sloane's *Theory of Error-Correcting Codes* (1978) under the name of the $|u|u+v|$ construction, and used in
several other places (chapters) in that tome.  As a special case, if 
$A$ is a $r$-th order binary
Reed-Muller code of length $2^m$ and $B$ is a $(r-1)$-th order binary
Reed-Muller code of length $2^m$, then $C$ is a $r$-th order binary Reed-Muller code of
length $2^{m+1}$.  Every polynomial $f$ of degree $r$ in $m+1$ variables can be expressed
as $f = g + x_{m+1}h$ where $g$ is a polynomial of degree $r$ in $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_m$
and $h$ is a polynomial of degree $r-1$ in $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_m$.
The codewords of the form $[\mathbf a, \mathbf a]$ are the truth tables of the
$g$ polynomials, while 
codewords of the form $[\mathbf 0, \mathbf b]$ are the truth tables of the 
$x_{m+1}h$ polynomials.
By truth table I mean that the codeword corresponding to 
$f(x_{m+1},x_m,\cdots, x_1) = g(x_m,\cdots, x_1)+x_{m+1}h(x_m,\cdots, x_1)$ is 
$$[f(\mathbf 0), f(\mathbf 1), \cdots, f(\mathbf{2^m-1}),f(\mathbf{2^m}), f(\mathbf{2^m+1}), \cdots,
f(\mathbf{2^{m+1}-1})]$$ where $\mathbf i$ is the binary representation of the integer $i$.
Note  that $\mathbf{2^m-1} = 011\cdots 11$ while $\mathbf{2^m} = 100\cdots 00$,
$\mathbf{2^m+1} = 100\cdots 01$,$~~\ldots$, $\mathbf{2^{m+1}-1} = 111\cdots 11$,
.
..
This idea was used extensively in the study of binary Reed-Muller codes,
including in the MacWilliams and Sloane book.